# uidgid file - UID in parentheses

Tags: rhel, uid

Looking at file */usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid* on RHEL7, I can see some lines containing `-`, `?` or number in parentheses:

```
...
nslcd   65  (55)    /       /sbin/nologin   nslcd
wine    -   66  -       -   wine
...
listar  ?   ?   ?       ?   listar
...
```

Meaning of `?` and `-` can be somehow implied, but what about the numbers in parentheses?

For example, what does `(100)` mean for `games` user, given `users` group has UID 100?

```
games   12  (100)   /usr/games      /sbin/nologin   setup
users   -   100 -       -   setup
```

Or better—is there an official explanation of the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The (100) seems to be assigning the default group of the user in /etc/passwd:

```
$ grep games /etc/passwd /etc/group
/etc/passwd:games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
/etc/group:games:x:20:
$ id games
uid=12(games) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```